# JavaFX: how to set correct tooltip position?

Tags: position, tooltip, javafx-2, javafx

I have a `TextField` for which I want a `Tooltip` to be shown under some circumstances.

After performing checks I run the followig code:

```
textFieldUsername.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Enter username!"));
textFieldUsername.getTooltip().setAutoHide(true);
textFieldUsername.getTooltip().show(textFieldUsername, 1, 1);
```

So when somebody tries to login with empty username he gets a prompting `Tooltip` over the "username" `TextField`.

But when it comes to action, the `Tooltip` pops up in the top left corner of the screen.

Should I calculate coords of my scene, then add my `TextField` coords to them, or there is a way to set these `1, 1` arguments from the call of `show()` to be relative to the `TextField` position?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the coordinates are always relative to the screen. To calculate component coordinates you need to incorporate scene and window coordinates.

```
Point2D p = label.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);
label.getTooltip().show(label,
        p.getX() + label.getScene().getX() + label.getScene().getWindow().getX(),
        p.getY() + label.getScene().getY() + label.getScene().getWindow().getY());
```

Comment: right, as stated in javadoc: "`public void show(Node ownerNode,
        double screenX,
        double screenY)`
Shows the popup at the specified x,y location relative to the **screen**."