# How to get TextField position

Tags: java, javafx-2, textfield

I was wondering is it possible to get position of `JavaFX` `TextField` control. Because, I would like to show `Popup` just below `TextField`. I noticed that there is no any method which returns this property. It there a any way to do this? Or should I use some other way to show `Popup` below `TextField`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use the [localToScene(double, double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToScene%28double,%20double%29) method to translate the starting x,y position of the `TextField` to a `Point2D`. This will then give you a point that contains the starting x,y position of the `TextField` within the [Scene](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html). From there you can set the position of your label relative to the starting position of the `TextField`.

```
    //TextField was declared and added to the Scene already
    Point2D point = myTextField.localToScene(0.0, 0.0);
```

You also my find this StackOverflow question helpful which describes [how to set a tool tip position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049362/javafx-how-to-set-correct-tooltip-position).

Comment: Ok,I will try that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the bounds in parent:

```
textField.getBoundsInParent()
```

and set your pop up coordinates relative to that position.

Usefull link: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/aim/archive/2009/01/layout_primer_f.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer may not be your best option if you have already got your PopUp to work.  it's just provided here as an alternative idea in case it's useful.

You can use a [ContextMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html) which allows you to [set a graphic node in a menu item](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#setGraphic(javafx.scene.Node)) (so it can really display anything) and has [show commands which position it relative to another node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html#show(javafx.scene.Node,%20javafx.geometry.Side,%20double,%20double)).

This is an option from the StackOverflow question: [JavaFX 2 custom popup pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717969/javafx-2-custom-popup-pane).