# JavaFX: how to set tooltip location relative to the mouse cursor?

Tags: javafx

I have some Buttons, and I have added tooltips to them.

```
Button button = new Button("Example");
Tooltip tt = new Tooltip("example");
button.setTooltip(tt);
```

By default, when I mouse over the button, the tooltip pops up; however, the tooltip appears under the cursor. I am looking for a way to change the default location of the tooltip when moused over to something like 10px right and down. Something like below:

```
tooltip.setLocation(mouseLocation+10, mouseLocation-10);
```

I looked at [JavaFX: how to set correct tooltip position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049362/javafx-how-to-set-correct-tooltip-position)
and it wasn't really what I was looking for because it is more about having the tooltip appear in relation to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Although the question is a little bit old,but remains unanswered.**

1. Part 1

> What about something that is using `Button` current position in screen
>   and set the tooltip position accordingly?

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Hey i am a Button"));
button.getTooltip().setOnShowing(s->{

    //Get button current bounds on computer screen
    Bounds bounds = button.localToScreen(button.getBoundsInLocal());
    button.getTooltip().setX(bounds.getMaxX());
    button.getTooltip().setY(bounds.getMinY());

});
```

2. Part 2

> (You can do also with mouse but add somewhere a mouseMoveListener,in
>   the example it is added on the `Button` but i would prefer to add it on
>   the `Stage` `Scene` if we are speaking about a lot of `Button`)

```
    double currentMouseX;
    double currentMouseY;
    button.setOnMouseMoved(m->{
        currentMouseX=m.getScreenX();
        currentMouseY=m.getScreenY();
    });

    button.getTooltip().setOnShowing(s->{       
        button.getTooltip().setX(currentMouseX+button.getTooltip().getWidth()+5);
        button.getTooltip().setY(currentMouseY);                
    });
```

> Finnaly:

Actually in the IDE you are using type `button.getTooltip().setOn..` and you will see all the available methods that you can use to control tooltip before and after showing or hiding.

Answer (score 0):

To get it relative to the mouse's position, you may use **robot**.

Example:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        com.sun.glass.ui.Robot robot =
        com.sun.glass.ui.Application.GetApplication().createRobot();
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Button btn = new Button("Stack");
        Tooltip tt = new Tooltip("example");
        tt.setX(robot.getMouseX()+10);
        tt.setY(robot.getMouseY()-10);
        btn.setTooltip(tt);
        pane.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not guaranteed to always work as it uses `com.sun` classes which can be deprecated and removed in subsequent JavaFX releases.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaFx 8 Tooltip provides event callbacks just before and after the tooltip displays (and just before and after it's taken down).   So, install an event handler for the "just before" call like this below.  The window event doesn't give you the current mouse coordinates, unfortunately, but you can still get them at any time with java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation() as below.

```
Tooltip t = new Tooltip();
Tooltip.install(yournode, t);
t.setOnShowing(ev -> {// called just prior to being shown
                Point mouse = java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                Point2D local = yournode.screenToLocal(mouse.x, mouse.y);

                // my app-specific code to get the char's yaxis value
                // then set the text as I want
                double pitch = yaxis.getValueForDisplay(local.getY()).doubleValue();
                double freq = AudioUtil.pitch2frequency(pitch);
                t.setText(String.format("Pitch %.1f:  %.1f Hz   %.1f samples", pitch, freq, audio.rate / freq));
        });
```

This worked for me.